# UICollectionView showing only one cell - which changes when the view is scrolled

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView which is supposed to show items from an array. I have checked the array - and it is populated with the right number and type of objects.

The UICollectionView however shows only one UICollectionView cell - and it changes when I pull the cell down to the previous object. I've not seen this behaviour before. Below is my code:

(It's the SourceTankCollectionView that is causing the problem (and I assume the destination collection view cell will too)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (collectionView==self.movementsIndexCollectionView)
    {

        TransfersListCollectionViewCell* tempCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Transfer List Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!tempCell)
        {
            tempCell = [[TransfersListCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        }

        Movement* thisMovement = [self.arrayOfAllMovements objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

        tempCell.sourceTankLabel.text = thisMovement.sourceTank.tankNumber;
        tempCell.destinationTankLabel.text = thisMovement.destinationTank.tankNumber;
        tempCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
        tempCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
        tempCell.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
        return tempCell;
    }

    else if (collectionView==self.sourceTanksCollectionView)
    {
        SourceTankCollectionViewCell* tempCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Source Tank Collection Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!tempCell)
        {
            tempCell = [[SourceTankCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        }
        int index = indexPath.row;

        if (!tempCell)
        {
            tempCell = [[SourceTankCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        }

        Tank* thisSourceTank = [self.arrayOfSourceTanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        Product* thisSourceTankProduct = thisSourceTank.tankProduct;

        tempCell.tankNumberLabel.text = thisSourceTank.tankNumber;
        tempCell.tankProductLabel.text = thisSourceTankProduct.name;
        tempCell.tankVolumeLabel.text = thisSourceTank.tankTotalVolume;
        tempCell.tankVolumeGauge.percentFilled = [thisSourceTank.tankTotalVolume doubleValue]/[thisSourceTank.tankMaxVolume doubleValue];
        //tempCell.tankVolumeToTransferLabel.text = [thisMovement.volume stringValue];
        //tempCell.tankVolumeTransferredLabel.text = @"35000";
        tempCell.transferStatusLabel.text = @"In progress";

        tempCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        tempCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
        tempCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        tempCell.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

        tempCell.frame = CGRectMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.9, 103);
        return tempCell;
    }
    else //if (collectionView==self.destinationTanksCollectionView)
    {
        DestinationTankCollectionViewCell* tempCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"Destination Tank Collection Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!tempCell)
        {
            tempCell = [[DestinationTankCollectionViewCell alloc] init];
        }
        Tank* thisDestinationTank = [self.arrayOfDestinationTanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        Product* thisDestinationTankProduct = thisDestinationTank.tankProduct;

        tempCell.tankNumberLabel.text = thisDestinationTank.tankNumber;
        tempCell.tankProductLabel.text = thisDestinationTankProduct.name;
        tempCell.tankVolumeLabel.text = thisDestinationTank.tankTotalVolume;
        tempCell.tankVolumeGauge.percentFilled = [thisDestinationTank.tankTotalVolume doubleValue]/[thisDestinationTank.tankMaxVolume doubleValue];

        tempCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        tempCell.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
        tempCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        tempCell.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

        tempCell.frame = CGRectMake(self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.destinationTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.9, 103);
        return tempCell;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (collectionView == self.movementsIndexCollectionView)
    {
        return self.arrayOfAllMovements.count;
    }
    else if (collectionView == self.sourceTanksCollectionView)
    {
        return self.arrayOfSourceTanks.count;
    }
    else //(collectionView == self.destinationTanksCollectionView)
    {
        return self.arrayOfDestinationTanks.count;
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any help! I assume it is an easy fix!

Comment: Make sure you are call reloadData from main thread

Comment: you only have this problem for SourceTankCollectionView? are you sure?

Comment: Only the one I describe above... unless it is a manifestation of many problems!

Comment: @C_X i do call reload data when i get my data in

Comment: @HillInHarwich and you are calling on main thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not supposed to set the frame of the UICollectionViewCell. You only can set the width and height. and that should be done in:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/2.0, collectionView.frame.size.height/2.0);
}
```

As I can observe all your cells for this collection view have the same frame rectangle. maybe that what is causing the problem. all the cells are on top of each other.

```
tempCell.frame = CGRectMake(self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.05, self.sourceTanksCollectionView.frame.size.width * 0.9, 103);
```

Answer (score 2):

@hasan83's answer in Swift 3:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width / 2.0, height: collectionView.frame.size.height / 2.0)
}
```